# One-to-Many with no back reference in sub-related entity

Tags: entity-relationship, multiple-resultsets, bltoolkit

If I have one-to-many relation between two entities (ie. `Post` and `Comment`) and have my *master* class defined as:

```
public class Post {
    ...
    IList<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

But my `Comment` sub-related class doesn't have a property of type `Post`, because there's never a need to get from comment to post. Comments are always displayed along with the master post instance.

Then I have a stored procedure that returns two result sets: posts and comments that are related to them. I define my `MapResultSet` as

```
MapResultSet[] sets = new MapResultSet[2];

sets[0] = new MapResultSet(typeof(Post), posts);
sets[1] = new MapResultSet(typeof(Comment));

sets[0].AddRelation(sets[1], /* what goes here? */, "PostID", "Comments");
```

But this doesn't work, since `Comment` doesn't have a reference to its `Post` hence I don't have anything to define for the second parameter in the upper code. If I provide `string.Empty` or `null` I get an exception if invalid method parameter.

**How should I define relationship between these two entities without adding a `Post` property to `Comment`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comment should have "PostId", if it doesn't it is impossible to define the post for the comment (for example in result sets we have 2 posts and 7 comments)

So you should add either Post property or PostId to the Comment class.

Also for simple cases please see the RelationAttribute, the example is [here](http://bltoolkit.net/Doc.ExecuteResultSet.ashx)
See Test2(), this helps to avoid manually relations prepare, no need to write:

```
sets[0].AddRelation(sets[1], "PostID", "PostID", "Comments");
```

Comment: Actually you're right. My code was returning a single post with comments. But multi resultset can't be aware of it. So I suppose you're answer should be accepted. :)